# How do I return a String Response to my Fragment form an API and update my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am relatively new to developing Android application. I tried searching for the answer everywhere even used OkHttp library but nothing seemed to work.

I have an application which displays data retrieved from an API in a fragment. I have an app drawer which is used to change what you want to see and switches to a new fragment.

What I want to achieve is connect to the internet and retrieve all the data as it is in a string format and assign it to a APIResponse String in my Fragment.

The code in which I have trouble is :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_newfragment, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    listdata = new ArrayList<>();
    DataReceivingClass dataReceivingClass;
    String APIResponse ="";

    APIResponse = /*Need to pass 2 String Parameters namely source and sort 
    which is required for generating the url as I want to reuse this code 
    over other fragments.
    Connect to the internet using the url and get the data in string format 
    and assign the returned string to APIResponse */

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    dataReceivingClass = gson.fromJson(APIResponse, DataReceivingClass.class);

    listdata = dataReceivingClass.getData();
```

I used all sorts of solutions I found. Created new myAsync class which inherited from AsyncTask and tried but still couldn't get it done.
My Application always used to crash.
and one time when it didn't crash it just worked according to the values I had passed to APIResponse initially and didn't update it later.
runOnUiThread function also seemed confusing and didn't seem to work. I was unable to use it.

Please tell me the code to make it run. A code which I can reuse in other fragments by just changing parameters passed as mentioned in my code will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible (and the response is a Json or XML), consider using a 3rd Party library (like Retrofit or Jackson) for handling your API calls, they are not very difficult to implement and save you a lot of time (and problems).

For handling the response, you can use Callbacks to "respond" when your request has ended.

```
public interface RequestCallback<T> {
   void onSuccess(T data);

   void onError(Object error);
}
```

Implement your Callback in your Fragment

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements RequestCallback<String> {
    ... your code ...

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String data) {
        // update UI
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Object error) {
        // show error
    }
}
```

Then you can use the Callback methods (passing the Fragment instance) when the request has finished. You can implement that Callback in every Fragment/Class that needs to "respond" your requests.

Also, there are other alternatives.

About runOnUiThread, every network request needs to be done in an separated Thread. But you can't interact with the UI on that Thread (I guess that's the reason your Application is crashing). So you use runOnUiThread() for execute your code on UI Thread to interact with the UI.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // update UI
    }
};
```

Alternatively you can use the Annotation @UiThread in a method to make sure that method is executed in the UI Thread.

```
@UiThread
public void updateUI() {
    // update UI
}
```

Also, if you're using AsyncTask you can update UI in onPostExecute(), which runs on UI Thread

```
class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    .. your code ..

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // update UI
    }
}
```

I hope I have helped.